# Mapping multiple source properties to a single destination property

Tags: c#, automapper

I'd like to know if there would be to a way to handle this kind of scenario with some custom type or value resolver.

```
public class SuperDateTime
{
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }

    public string Timezone { get; set; }
}

public class Entity 
{
    public DateTimeOffset CreationDate { get; set; }

    public string CreationDateZone { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset EndDate { get; set; }

    public string EndDateZone { get; set; }
}

public class Model
{
    public SuperDateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public SuperDateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

When i have a `SuperDateTime` in the destination object, i'd like to instantiate this object with the associated `DateTimeOffset` and the timezone `string` in the source object.

Of course what i'd like to do is to make something generic, so not going thought the `MapFrom` in each `CreateMap` of every `Entity`

I tried to do it with a custom TypeConverter but it supports only a SourceType -> DestinationType
In my case i have a `string` and `DateTimeOffset` that has to create a `SuperDateTime`

Comment: In addition to my response below, is there any value in defining a struct (e.g. SuperDateTimeDto) for use in source type? You could then define a custom value resolver from the struct to the destination SuperDateTime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what LiamK is suggesting, the next possible improvement is to write a helper method for doing `.MapFrom`. Depending on your requirements it can be simple or complex. I'm going to offer a simple one that makes a lot of assumptions, but you can modify and optimize it to suit your possible requirements.

```
static IMappingExpression<TFrom, TTo> MapSuperDateTime<TFrom, TTo>(
    this IMappingExpression<TFrom, TTo> expression, 
    Expression<Func<TTo, object>> dest)
{
    var datePropertyName = ReflectionHelper.FindProperty(dest).Name;
    var timezomePropertyName = datePropertyName + "Zone";
    var fromType = typeof (TFrom);
    var datePropertyGetter = fromType.GetProperty(datePropertyName).ToMemberGetter();
    var timezonePropertGetter = fromType.GetProperty(timezomePropertyName).ToMemberGetter();

    return expression.ForMember(dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new SuperDateTime
    {
        Date = (DateTimeOffset)datePropertyGetter.GetValue(src),
        Timezone = (string)timezonePropertGetter.GetValue(src)         
    }));
}
```

And then you can specify your mapping like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, Model>()
    .MapSuperDateTime(dest => dest.CreationDate)
    .MapSuperDateTime(dest => dest.EndDate);
```

The assumption is that if your Entity `DateTimeOffset` is called bla, then your corresponding Entity `string` is called blaZone, and your Model `SuperDateTime` is called bla.

Comment: +1 for consolidating everything down to a helper method for OP. This is the most simplified method of having to do a repeated mapping I can think of.

Comment: @LiamK Thank you, I think we can make it even more generic. I added one more answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Customer Resolver for this. I used custom resolver for getting an object from int something like this;

Lets say you are creating a mapping like this(Althoug you didn't show how you are creating it):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<YourSource, YourDestination>()
                .ForMember(x => x.DateTimeOffset, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(new DateTimeOffsetResolver(loadRepository)).FromMember(x => x.timezone));
```

And this how your resolver will look like:

```
public class DateTimeOffsetResolver : ValueResolver<string, DateTimeOffset>
    {
        private DatabaseLoadRepository loadRepository;
        public personIdResolver(DatabaseLoadRepository repo)
        {
            this.loadRepository = repo;
        }
        protected override DateTimeOffset ResolveCore(string timeZone)
        {
            //Your logic for converting string into dateTimeOffset goes here
            return DateTimeOffset; //return the DateTimeOffset instance
        }
    }
```

You can remove all the code related to Nhibernate Repository if you not need to access it.
You can further read about custom resolvers [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers)

Comment: The OP's question was actually directed add getting a custom value resolver for <string, DateTimeOffset> => SuperDateTime. This solution addresses the very different question of mapping string => DateTimeOffset

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to you question is 'No', there isn't way to use a custom value resolver to map < string, DateTimeOffset > => SuperDateTime and avoid the repeated .MapFrom calls. In your example above, such a value resolver wouldn't be able to distinguish *which* strings and DateTimeOffsets went together during mapping.

Not sure if you have the .MapFrom code yourself, but if not, below is the best solution to your problem:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, Model>()
      .ForMember(
           dest => dest.CreationDate,
           opt => opt.MapFrom(
               src => new SuperDateTime()
                     {
                           Date = src.CreationDate, 
                           TimeZone = src.CreationDateZone
                     };
            ));
```

If you really want to avoid excessive MapFrom declarations, see if there's a way to leverage mapping inheritance here.

EDIT: Modified instantiation of SuperDateTime to match the provided source code.

Comment: According to the OP SuperDateTime does not have a constructor with two parameters. Are you suggesting to add one? (If you are, it's not clear from your answer)

Comment: My assumption was that the full source wasn't included in the post. If there indeed isn't a viable parameterized constructor, it's easy enough to instantiate the properties using setters. The .MapFrom function takes a Func<T> parameter. The OP can do whatever is necessary to instantiate the object inside the anonymous function. The details of instantiating the SuperDateTime object seemed irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

After sleeping on it, here is an alternative that feels more generic.

Assume, you want to do something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, Model>()
    .ForMemberType((member,src) => new SuperDateTime
            {
                Date = (DateTimeOffset)GetPropertyValue(src, member),
                Timezone = (string)GetPropertyValue(src, member+"Zone")
            });
```

This looks a bit nicer then my first answer, because here you specify that you want to map all members of `SuperDateTime` at once. (The type is inferred from the return type of the lambda.) Really, similar to `ForAllMembers` that AutoMapper already has. The only problem that you cannot use standard `memberOptions` as `IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource>` does not give you access to the member currently being configured. For brevity, I removed the `memberOptions` parameter from `ForMemberType` signature completely, but it is very easy to add it back if you need that (that is to set some other options too - see example [here](https://gist.github.com/AndrewSav/16a101482bf5f61392d2)).

So in order to be able to write the above all you need is `GetPropertyValue` method, that can look like this:

```
public object GetPropertyValue(object o, string memberName)
{
    return o.GetType().GetProperty(memberName).ToMemberGetter().GetValue(o);
}
```

And the `ForMemberType` method itself, which would look like that:

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> ForMemberType<TSource, TDestination, TMember>(
    this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression,
    Func<string, TSource, TMember> memberMapping
    )
{
    return new TypeInfo(typeof(TDestination))
        .GetPublicReadAccessors()
        .Where(property => property.GetMemberType() == typeof(TMember))
        .Aggregate(expression, (current, property)
            => current.ForMember(property.Name, 
               opt => opt.MapFrom(src => memberMapping(property.Name, src))));
}
```

And that's it. To avoid recompiling the property getter every time, you might want to add a very simple caching layer that compiles (executes `ToMemberGetter`) once for each type and remembers the result somewhere. Using AutoMapper own `DictonaryFactory` and then `IDictionary.GetOrAdd` is probably the most straight forward way of doing this:

```
private readonly IDictionary<string, IMemberGetter> _getters 
    = new DictionaryFactory().CreateDictionary<string, IMemberGetter>();        
public object GetPropertyValue(object o, string memberName)
{
    var getter = _getters.GetOrAdd(memberName + o.GetType().FullName, x => o.GetType()
        .GetProperty(memberName).ToMemberGetter());
    return getter.GetValue(o);
}
```